# Hover&Focus problem with tabs only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a hover/focus problem where when you hover over the tabs the titles are moving a bit to the right, if you click on the second or third tab it corrects itself automatically and after that it also stays like that. Means only the first hover is changing the position of the title. On top of that the problem appears only in  Firefox.

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjmG0.png)

[How it looks after hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX3gB.png)

You can reproduce the problem on Firefox on following site:

https://shop.von-lupin.com/marketing/kosmetik-partner-werden/

I though it has something to do with:

```
.wp-block-ub-tabbed-content-tabs-title:hover, .wp-block-ub-tabbed-content-tabs-title:focus {


 overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I played a bit around with it but couldnt find a solution.

No one an idea?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.